# Can Bolts Tasks run in Parallel bolts return non-Void types on Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, parse-platform, parallel-processing, bolts-framework

I'm trying to use the Facebook / Parse Bolts framework to run multiple tasks in parallel on Android. The [documentation for running tasks in parallel](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android#tasks-in-parallel) seems to indicate that the result of [whenAll](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android/blob/42c943bf8eeb837323b32c57fe34bea48cdc52c6/bolts-tasks/src/main/java/bolts/Task.java#L403) will always be Void.

Is there a way to get the actual result of one or more of the parallelized Tasks?

Comment: It occurs to me that perhaps I could use an event bus (like Otto) to accomplish a similar thing? I don't know enough about thread enforcement on an event bus to be sure tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the result of the tasks like this:

```
ArrayList<Task<Boolean>> tasks = getTasks();
Task.whenAll(tasks).onSuccess(new Continuation<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void then(Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
        for (Task<Boolean> t : tasks) {
            doSomething(t.getResult());
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the continuation on the `whenAll`, you can get the results directly from the sub-tasks:

```
final Task<A> a = // ...
final Task<B> b = // ...

Task.whenAll(Arrays.asList(a, b)).continueWithTask((t) -> {
  if (!a.isFaulted()) {
    return doSomethingAsync(a.getResult());
  }
  if (!b.isFaulted()) {
    return doSomethingElseAsync(b.getResult());
  }

  // ...

  return t;
});
```